# Opposite partner's opening bid, should I respond in a long minor or a shorter major?

Tags: bridge, bidding

At matchpoints, vulnerable versus not, my partner opened 1 heart with (s) QT963 (h) AKJ92 (d)Q4 (c)8.

I responded 2 diamonds with (s)A872 (h) 8 (d) KJT753 (c) KQ. Partner rebid 2 spades and we ended up in 4 spades, which went down one. A 5 diamond contract would probably have made because partner and I had a straight sequence in diamonds (K-T) versus a broken sequence in spades (with KJx "offside" partner's five card suit).

One of my opponents (the club expert) asked me why I didn't respond one spade instead.   of two diamonds. I said that I preferred the minor suit because it was two  cards longer (six versus four), and I felt that it would be easier to get a nine card fit in diamonds with partner having three out of the seven diamonds not in my hand than an eight card fit in spades with partner needing four of the nine spades not in my hand. (I prefer a nine card fit when playing for game in a minor.) As it turned out, we had only an eight card fit in diamonds, but experts such as Marty Bergen have opined that a good top sequence (e.g. K-T) is worth an extra card of length (e.g. nine instead of eight).

Was my opponent right to insist that I respond in spades, or did I do well to respond two diamonds? Also, could partner have made things easier by opening one spade instead of one heart.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly normal to bid your longest suit first as responder when you have game forcing values. In fact, if you are playing a system in which a 2D response to 1H is forcing to game, it is much, much better to respond 2D with your hand than 1S. Even in Standard American, it is better to respond 2D than 1S when you have game forcing values and hold four spades and five diamonds.

A few notes on the actual hand:

- I'm not really sure how you plan to make 5D. It seems you must lose a club, a diamond, and at least one spade, unless opening leader underleads a spade honor and declarer guesses which one. It seems in most cases, diamonds and spades make the same number of tricks unless defenders can arrange to ruff a diamond in a spade contract. Either way, diamonds goes down, and spades may or may not make.
- With exactly 5-5 distribution in the majors, you open 1S, not 1H, regardless of strength. Depending on agreements, there are two ways that this auction should have gone in a fairly standard American system.

Option 1:

```
1S   2NT*   *Jacoby 2NT: game forcing raise with 4 or more trumps
4H*  4S     *Good 5-card heart suit on the side
```

Responder signs off with shortness in opener's side suit.

Option 2:

```
1S    4H*   *Splinter: 4-card support, shortness in hearts, GF
4S
```

Opener signs off with wastage in responder's short suit and no significant extras.

Some partnerships play that responder's hand is too strong for the splinter and so prefer the Jacoby 2NT response, and others do not.

Answer (score -1):

Your partner should have opened 1S, as they don’t have sufficient points or the right shape for a reverse.

However, why not bid 1S yourself?  Sure, nine diamonds would be a nice fit, but 10 tricks is easier to take than eleven, and the nice unbroken sequence is several tricks no matter what trump is. Seems to me that even a 4-4 fit would be fine given your honor in spades.

Turns out you go down one, but that’s just bad luck (or bad play); you only go down if you lose two trump tricks, either to a singleton diamond lead and then ruff with the king protected beyond that, or KJx to your right in spades.  Both are unlikely.

In any event, you’re both wrong for not bidding spades. Bid based on shape more than suit quality at these stages.

Comment: It seems hard to believe that a 4-4 spade fit will be lost after a 2D response, and easy to believe that a diamond game or slam will be lost if you show your 4-card suit before your 5-card suit.